# Cant get CSS to display with my HTML in notepad++

Tags: css

im sure im doing something wrong but I am attempting to learn to build a webpage on notepad++ I have made my html file and my css file seperate. Saved them both in the same project folder, linked the css to my HTML but when I run the HTML on a browser the CSS doesnt show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

    <head>
        <title>Coming soon!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li>Find Cards</li>
                    <li>About us</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>Log In</li>
                    <li>Sign up</li>
                    <li>Help</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                 <h1> Store & Event Locator</h1>

                <p>Find a place to buy, trade, or play at home or on the road</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
             <h2>Buy or Trade</h2>

            <p>From store fronts, online, to private collectors, we connect you with traders around the country</p>
            <p><a href="#"> Buy or Trade</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="learn-more">
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                     <h3>Show off your skills</h3>

                    <p>Have a new deck? let's see what you've got. Here you can find Events, game nights, and casual play.</p>
                    <p><a href="#"> Find games</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and

```
.nav a {
      color: #5a5a5a;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      }
```

but when I try to run it shows without the css just the HTML

Anything I found on this has not included an actual answer that fixes this problem just peoples thoughts. Please help so I can move on to the next step.

Comment: check the path of your style.css. Also there is no `<a href="" ...</a>` in `nav` section so, adding the `.nav a` in css won't work.

Comment: have you tried styling just `.nav`?

Comment: You sir thank you very much. That was it! I simply was trying to style something that was not there to begin with. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your directory structure something like this

```
--Root
   --index.html
   --style.css
```

Change your HTML **from this**

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
 <ul>
  <li>Find Cards</li>
  <li>About us</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li>Log In</li>
  <li>Sign up</li>
  <li>Help</li>
</ul>
```

**TO**`

```
 <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Find Cards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </div>`
```

Further, check console for any error.

Do come back if any issue.!

Comment: Yes thank you I simply didnt have an <a href="#"> in nav to style. I believe i gave you positive feedback for it but I am still new. Thanks again!